# jQuery: how to select a div and show / hide its nested div

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to show / hide a DIV when a user clicks on its corresponding parent DIV.

HTML:

```
<div class="header" id="header_1"> </div>
  <div class="body" id="body_1"> </div>


<div class="header" id="header_2">  </div>
  <div class="body" id="body_2"> </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.body')hide(); <--- hide all on load
$('.header').click(function(){
     var currentHeader = $(this).attr('id');

     //some logic to show the body div below the header that was clicked, and hide all the others 

 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a clever workaround: (thanks for your help, though! :-) )

HTML:

```
<ul> 
<li class='title' id='title 2> </li> 
<li class='section' id ='section 2'> </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.title').click(function(){
    $('.section').slideUp('fast');
    $(this).siblings('.section').slideDown('fast');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hide all the `body` divs then using the div that was clicked, get the next div with the body class applied

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hDzrR/)

```
$('.header').click(function(){
     var currentHeader = $(this);
     // hide all the body divs
     $('.body').hide();
     // show the next body div
     currentHeader.next('.body').show();

});
```

Comment: Sorry, my HTML was wrong. It has since been corrected - my body elements are NOT contained inside the parent header element...any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code does show/hide child elements when click on header. [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q3Spk/1/)

```
$('.body').hide();
$('.header').click(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('Active')) {
        $(this).find('.body').show();//show child div
        $(this).addClass('Active');
    } else {
        $(this).find('.body').hide();//hide child div
        $(this).removeClass('Active');
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').on('click.headerClick', '.header:has(.body)', function (e) {
  $('.header .body').not($(this).find('.body').show()).hide();
});
```

- This code uses [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events), assigning only a single listener, on the `<body>`-element, listening for click events on any element that has the class `header`, with at least one descendant that has a class `body`. If such an element is clicked, it shows any descendant elements of the clicked `header` having a class `body`, after that, it hides all elements with class `body` that has an ancestor with class `header`.
- The click event is [namespaced](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events). This allows us to unbind the event handler easily without conflicting with other event handlers bound to the same element.

[Demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/aeULd/1/)

Comment: Sorry, my HTML was wrong. It has since been corrected - my body elements are NOT contained inside the parent header element...any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
$(".header").on("click", function() {
    $(".body").not($(this).find(".body").show()).hide();
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/8UCma/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to  hide all elements and then show only the current one:

```
$('.body').hide();
$('.header').click(function(){
    // hide all other elements        
    $('.body').hide();
    // show the current one
    $(":first-child", $(this)).show();
});
```

A better solution would be, if you store a reference to the current active element.

```
var activeElement = null;

$('.body').hide();
$('.header').click(function(){
    // hide the last one     
    if(activeElement) {
        activeElement.hide();
    }
    // show the current one
    activeElement = $(":first-child", $(this));
    activeElement.show();

});
```